# How can I debug EnableCorsAttribute in Web Api to see why requests get denied?

Tags: .net, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I currently have a strange situation whereby all IE and Chrome requests work fine, but firefox gets denied for some reason. Firefox NET tab just says 'request aborted' so I need a way to debug this inside WEB API and see why my request is being denied. How can I do this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Web API service doesn't do anything different based on browser types, there should be a difference in how the requests differ between the browsers...so i would try this: Open `Fiddler` and trace the request in case of working browser and also trace the request in terms of non-working browser. Now Fiddler provides a nice capability of comparing trace sessions. This should give you the difference between the working and non-working browser.